# Can I access a project's class and methods from an another project in the same solution?

Tags: c#

I have two project in one solution. The first has ClassLibrary as output and the second is a WPF project. There is a method in the first project i want to access to from the second project but i can't. I tell me that the fonction doesn't existe.

I have already tried to add to the second project the reference using the Add Reference menu. In the second project referencies tree the first project is present.
I included the namespace : using firstproject;

First project code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void displayTest()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World !");
        }

    }
}
```

Second project code :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using ClassLibrary2;

namespace CpowerPos
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logique d'interaction pour MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonConnection(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            displayTest();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do these changes :
1. Make "displayTest" as static
2. Create dll of first project and add in to second
It should be acceess form second project

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an *instance* of the class before you can call it.

You can do it like this:

```
var c1 = new Class1();
c1.displayTest();
```

Or you can make it a one-liner:

```
new Class1().displayTest();
```

Answer (score 0):

You done all the process what we need to follow for integrating class library project to WPF application.

You just miss to Create instance of `Class1` in `MainWindow`

To instantiate Class1 in MainWindow, you can use new operator

```
Class1 c1 = new Class1(); //This will create instance of class1
c1.displayTest()    //This will call display function
```

Do not miss to include namespace of Class1. (That you have done already in your project i.e. `using ClassLibrary2;`)

Answer (score 0):

Project 1

```
public static class Class1
{      
      public static void displayTest()
       {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World !");
        }    
    }
```

Project 2

```
 private void ButtonConnection(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Class1.displayTest();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add reference of first project dll to the second project. Right click -> Add reference -> choose the dll of first project. and then include the namespace of type from first project you are trying to access. Moreover your posted code shouldn't compile in first place since there no `displayTest()` method as member to the type as well it's a instance method. Thus you will have to create an instance of `Class1` before accessing it

```
    private void ButtonConnection(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 c = new Class1();
        c.displayTest();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have indeed enabled access to "ClassLibrary2" from inside CpowerPos.
The problem is neither "Class1", nor "DisplayText" are static, therefore they do not exist (yet), as far as the code is concerned.

You can either make "DisplayText" static, allowing you to call 'Class1.DisplayText()', or you make an instance:

```
Class1 libraryClass = new Class1();
libraryClass.DisplayText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Methods is part of class so you need to create instance of Class1 class to be able to call displayTest method.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonConnection(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var myObj = new Class1();
            myObj.displayTest();
        }
    }
```

Or you can make the method static and call without creating of instance.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonConnection(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Class1.displayTest();
        }
    }
```

Also c# allows you to access static members and nested types of a type without having to qualify the access with the type name.

```
using static ClassLibrary2.Class1;
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonConnection(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            displayTest();
        }
    }
```